# How to find particular text from td tag using bs4

Tags: regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

This is my first post

I have some html links and i want to find some particular text and it's next text also. I am using regex but receiving lost of empty lists.

These are links:

https://www.99acres.com/mailers/mmm_html/eden-park-14mar2017-558.html
https://www.99acres.com/mailers/mmm_html/ats-golf-meadows-13april-2016.html
https://www.99acres.com/mailers/mmm_html/spaze-privy-the-address-10mar2017-553.html

text i am finding 
Area Range: Next Text also
Possession: next text also for example possession 2019
Price: next text also

below are my codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import json
import itertools
import re
file = {}
final_data = []
final = []
textdata = []
def readfile(alldata, filename):
    with open("./"+filename, "w") as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for i in range(0, len(alldata)):
            csvfile.writerow(alldata[i])
def parsedata(url, values):
    r = requests.get(url, values)
    data = r.text
    return data

def getresults():
    global final_data, file
    with open("Mailers.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            ids = row[0]
            link = row[1]
            html = parsedata(link, {})
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            titles = soup.title.text
            td = soup.find_all("td")
            for i in td:
                sublist = []
                data = i.text
                pattern = r'(Possession:)(.)(.+)'
                x1 = re.findall(pattern, data)
                sublist.append(x1)
                sublist.append(link)
                final_data.append(sublist)
    print(final_data)
    return final_data
def main():
    getresults()
    readfile(final_data, "Data.csv")
main()
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now? It's unclear what your exact question is.

Comment: wrong is i am receiving too many empty lists and it is delaying my code and is this correct way?. I am trying to look for some particular texts and there next text too from td tag.